# Eager Loading on 3 Models in Laravel 5

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, eager-loading

I have 3 Models that are related so : 
"Tutorial" belongs To "Title" that belongs to "Course". Or (the other way) . A "Course" has many "Titles" that have many "Tutorials" . 
And I want to find a course based on its id and grab all its titles and tutorials using the eager loading . 
the code looks so :

```
$course = Course::with('titles')->where('id','=',$id)->get();
```

// this returns only a Course with its titles , but I want to get also tutorials that belongs to each title.

Comment: What have you tried so far? As eager loading is covering in the online Laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: I just edited my Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eager load nested relations with the dot-syntax as documented [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading)

```
$course = Course::with('titles.tutorials')->find($id);
```

As you can see I also changed the `where('id', '=', $id)` to `find($id)`. This will do the same but also only return one result instead of a collection.